# Designing scrollable option selector for android

Tags: android, menu, android-button

Hi below is screen shot of the UI i need to develop.Here each button is scrollable text character so my widget should give option to scroll and read current displayed character. Please advice me for my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhyW8.png

Comment: it is something like date widget but i don't want plus and minus button user should scroll to see next option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to develop a custom View implementation to handle this.  See the tutorial on developer.android.com at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html for information on how to do this.  If you have any more specific questions, please post them in detail.